# Which laptop should I buy for dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10?

Tags: laptop, linux, ubuntu

I  require to dual boot Ubuntu LTS 18.04 along with Windows 10. Which laptop would you recommend to do so? I would need a good community to troubleshoot with, documentation, step-by-step guides to dual boot Ubuntu on that particular laptop. My minimum storage and RAM requirements are respectively 512 GB, 16 GB. The laptop should have good I/O. The laptop would be used for video editing and playing GTA V and Rainbow Six Siege along with Rocket League, along with a bit of machine learning (thus CUDA support and tensor flow). I would need 8+ hours of battery life when web browsing, watching video/movies, coding. The laptop should also not have any major issues (like overheating for instance) and should last me for a couple of years. The processor needs to be Intel and discrete GPU NVIDIA.

Comment: Maybe try to be more specific. "Good I/O" is rather ambiguous. Which ports do you really need? Which size of laptop do you prefer? What price range are you looking at. Also, I don't think that a dual-boot tutorial for your particular laptop should be a major concern. The process is pretty much the same for all Windows laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo ThinkPads are excellent and are available and their [P series machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_P_series#Fourth_generation) such as [this P53](https://www.staples.com/lenovo-thinkpad-p53s-20n6-15-6-notebook-intel-i7-16gb-memory-windows-10-professional-20n6001uus/product_IM16JV774)  are excellent performers for gaming and video work.  If you need to scale down in cost, the  [W  series machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_W_series) are very reasonably priced in the resale market.

Thinkpads are still professionally serviced by IBM Global as well as everyone else, and Lenovo publishes the most detailed and accurate hardware manuals.  There are very popular in the https://Askubuntu.com community as well as elsewhere. Lenovo also provides excellent support for Ubuntu, as I found when refurbishing them at https://freegeek.org .

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers